# Using two class attributes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jQuery validationEngine.js plugin for validating input fields. It requires me to add a `class="validate[required] text-input"` so it can validate when submit the form. But I have class="form-control" and, due to this, the validation is not working. If I remove `class="form-control"` validation will work but input box will be misaligned. Is there any way I can keep both? Or any other solution for this problem ? Thanks!

```
<input 
  name="selectAgent" 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  id="selectAgent" 
  class="validate[required] text-input" 
>
```

Comment: [tag:jquery-validate] is not the same as [tag:jquery-validation-engine].  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all your classes at once.  Having two class declarations can cause an error.

Use (notice how `form-control` is added to the end of your class with a `space` that is how you can add another class)

```
<input 
  name="selectAgent" 
  type="text" 
  id="selectAgent" 
  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" 
>
```

Instead of

```
<input 
  name="selectAgent" 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  id="selectAgent" 
  class="validate[required] text-input" 
>
```